# visual studio code html css javascript program not appearing correctly in my browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am working with that tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WaohfclZRs (the link is the third video in that series, I've programmed along with the first and second one)

Now I've installed Visual Studio Code and installed all the extensions like "Live Server" and everything. I've coded along with this tutorial. But when I click on "Open with Live Server" at the index.html-file it opens only the html-file. I've coded the main.scss and the _config.scss files as well. So everything that I've coded there does not appear.

I mean, it should be logical: When I click on index.html to "Open with Live Server" it runs only that html-file in my browser, not anything with scss... But I don't know what I should do so that the main.scss file and the _config.scss file are executed as well in my browser.

What should I do?

Edit from 28.08.2020:
So I've tried what you've told me and it still isn't working.

[This is what my Visual Studio Code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNpMy.png)

[This is what I see when I open it with the extention "Sass Live Compiler, e.g. when I click on Watch Sass down there and then on go Live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQt0T.png)

[This is what it looks like when I open it with a right click on index.html and click on "Open with Live Server"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeG7O.png)

I've checked that node.js and visual studio are installed correctly. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: If you right click on the `index.html` can you see run with live server?

Comment: If I right click on the index.html I can see Open with Live Server, not Run with Live Server. When I click it only the content of the index.html file appears. Nothing more that I need

Comment: !!Browser work only with css file not SCSS, you need compille it to css with GULP for example

Comment: Did you know how to working with Node.js? Did you working with gulp?

Comment: before start working with scss files you need to set up environment (Node.js, gulp, gulp-sass...)

Comment: Like @Greg-- Has mentioned you can't run `scss` in the browser and will need to be converted to `css` before running. I suggest you stick with using `css` while you learn more and then move onto `scss` later. [Here](https://medium.com/@brianhan/watch-compile-your-sass-with-npm-9ba2b878415b) is a good article for `scss` to `css`.

Comment: @Alexa0211 there is some documentation that you need install node.js and how to config tasks for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_transpiling-sass-and-less-into-css)

Comment: Here is the github page: https://AlexaSc0211.github.io/modern_portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the error, but maybe you are not compiling sass files, like said in the comments. Saas files are not able to run in the browser, just CSS files.

To compile sass or scss files in VScode, I recommend an extension called Live Saas Compiler, which will compile the sass files and generate a css file.

Comment: So now I installed Live Sass Compiler. I executed everything, watched that my code matches the code from the tutorial and it still doesn`t work. There is only the code from index.html executed.

Comment: There are no problems in each code... I am sorry, I don't know what to do...

Comment: where is css file was saved? did you change name and path to css file in html?

Comment: In html there is written <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">, I didn't change that. No name change, no path change.

Comment: Do you have this code on GitHub? This way we could see it and try to figure out what is the problem...

Comment: https://github.com/AlexaSc0211/modern_portfolio https://AlexaSc0211.github.io/modern_portfolio Basically it's only the code from the tutorial. Before I add something to it, it would be nice if it worked properly.

Comment: I did not see any errors and I will keep looking. But first, I have a question: are you trying to link index.html to dist/css/main.css or to scss/main.css? Because in index.html, the link goes to dist/css folder.

Comment: I think there could be the problem. The code of the tutorial is available here: https://github.com/bradtraversy/modern_portfolio/tree/master/dist . If you look at it, in dist/css/main.css there is a ton of code. In my dist/css/main.css there is literally nearly nothing. Why does he has that much code in it and I don't? I followed the tutorial and coded everything the way he did...

Comment: Also, in scss there are the main.css file and the main.scss.map files which aren't there at brad traversys code. How can I fix this? paste and delete?

Comment: Thank you very much... I think I am trying it again.

Comment: Yeah. I think the way to go is paste and delete. If you found my answer helpful, accept it as the answer. That helps my stack overflow reputation a lot ;)